# How sem_post/sem_wait differntiate between memory based and kernel based semaphore

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, posix

Not able to figure out , how sem_post/sem_wait functions differentiate between memory based and kernel based semaphore passed to them ?
For kernel based semaphore(named semaphore) it would require system call to do any operation.
For memory based no system call required to do any operation.
Suppose we created a named semaphore sem1 using sem_open call. 
Then under /dev/shm shows a file appears for this semaphore ls -l /dev/shm/sem.* -rw-r----- 1 root root 16 Jan 12 14:38 sem.sem1. 
As this is file ,so when we access it via sem_post/sem_wait we would require to do system call.
Or else they are mapped in process address space at time of sem_open then we won't require system call in sem_post/sem_wait.
So which is the correct way for named semaphore ?

Comment: What do you mean by "**kernel** based semaphore"? Both named and unnamed semaphores are placed in the memory accessible from the user-space application.

Comment: With that information the question has much more sense. Could you incorporate this information into the question post itself? On Stack Overflow we want the question to be **understandable without reading the comments**.